# Windows Service Bus and Network Load Balancing

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, port-forwarding, nlb

I'm looking to build an HA service bus farm, hopefully using Microsoft NLB on Windows Server 2012 R2, something like what is described [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/160fadb6-8910-468e-8049-0ffc466ae87d/high-availability-for-service-bus-11-queues-through-load-balancer?forum=servbus).

In the output below 9354 belongs to Microsoft.ServiceBus.Gateway.exe and 9356 belongs to Microsoft.ServiceBus.MessageBroker.exe.

My question is which port(s) do I ask NLB to forward?

```
netstat -anop TCP | find ":93"
TCP    0.0.0.0:9354           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       11424
TCP    0.0.0.0:9355           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
TCP    0.0.0.0:9356           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       12184
TCP    0.0.0.0:9359           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
```

Answer (score 2):

In our enviroment we set up a Service Bus Farm DNS and balance Service Bus traffic for ports 9354 and 9355, because only this ports are presented in Service Bus connection string.

We use LVS (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Virtual_Server) instead of NLB but I don't think this could be an issue for you.